# pgfplots, representing bars from same category and series adjacently

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, ticks

I would like to represent the number of counts from specific cell types on a bar chart. The cells are from different mutants, consequently there are four series (742, 743, 744, 745). However there are often counts from more than one cell on each sample.

It was possible to do this in gnumeric, although rather unattractive.

[image: Example of formatting using gnumeric]

When I try in pgfplots it the bars in the same horizontal position, which is a bit misleading when looking at the graph:

[image: Example of formatting using pgfplots]

Is it possible to separate them out so they sit side by side?

This is the full code used for the pgfplots graph:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,]
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,
    scale=1.8,
    legend style={
        at={(.15,0.5)},
        anchor=south
        },
    ylabel={counts},
    symbolic x coords={xylem,metaxylem,parenchyma near,parenchyma far,endodermis,cortex},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={
        rotate=90,
        anchor=east,
        major tick length=0pt,
        },
    ytick={0,1E-5,2E-5,3E-5,4E-5,5E-5},
    minor y tick num=1,
    minor x tick num=1,
    ]


     \addplot 
 coordinates{
(xylem,4.77115957680291E-07)
(xylem,4.80700458746295E-07)
(xylem,6.18930207436045E-07)
(xylem,0)
(xylem,0)
(metaxylem,1.36717438165697E-06)
(metaxylem,8.6587710838275E-07)
(parenchyma near,1.40074803102931E-05)
(parenchyma near,5.6128882652721E-06)
(parenchyma near,3.52571708015267E-05)
(parenchyma near,1.92039172966317E-05)
(parenchyma near,1.91236661974104E-05)
(parenchyma near,2.35518573480108E-05)
(parenchyma far,7.43951692166563E-07)
(parenchyma far,8.88923267160998E-07)
(parenchyma far,3.6268814728485E-06)
(parenchyma far,1.09732874594568E-06)
(parenchyma far,8.53068275418508E-07)
(endodermis,2.57085162076528E-06)
(endodermis,3.29317195319341E-06)
(endodermis,4.94702484448028E-06)
(endodermis,2.13922579718091E-06)
(endodermis,2.22654113584136E-06)
(endodermis,4.12652290509265E-06)
(endodermis,1.17511893280516E-06)
(endodermis,6.53785861610346E-06)
(endodermis,4.47396914912963E-06)
(cortex,9.83914129289644E-06)
(cortex,1.86715647599582E-05)
(cortex,0)
};
     \addplot 
 coordinates{
(xylem,7.53945434084153E-07)
(xylem,1.37415765387096E-06)
(xylem,0)
(xylem,0)
(xylem,0)
(metaxylem,1.98247542614061E-06)
(metaxylem,0)
(parenchyma near,3.68316451637233E-06)
(parenchyma near,8.0777112275819E-06)
(parenchyma near,0)
(parenchyma near,0)
(parenchyma near,0)
(parenchyma near,0)
(parenchyma far,6.77656020223033E-07)
(parenchyma far,9.71881811732259E-07)
(parenchyma far,0)
(parenchyma far,0)
(parenchyma far,0)
(endodermis,1.08336656049687E-06)
(endodermis,1.39949378109776E-06)
(endodermis,1.91375090130445E-06)
(endodermis,1.13971032622582E-06)
(endodermis,1.00361006441752E-06)
(endodermis,0)
(endodermis,0)
(endodermis,0)
(endodermis,0)
(cortex,1.05480628479098E-06)
(cortex,2.26710233848155E-06)
(cortex,1.76455333227908E-06)
};
     \addplot 
 coordinates{
(xylem,1.44022978099178E-06)
(xylem,0)
(xylem,0)
(xylem,0)
(xylem,0)
(metaxylem,6.05958746456549E-07)
(metaxylem,0)
(parenchyma near,2.63354304294999E-06)
(parenchyma near,0)
(parenchyma near,0)
(parenchyma near,0)
(parenchyma near,0)
(parenchyma near,0)
(parenchyma far,1.60959732610717E-06)
(parenchyma far,0)
(parenchyma far,0)
(parenchyma far,0)
(parenchyma far,0)
(endodermis,5.00987747409934E-06)
(endodermis,1.98538914922263E-05)
(endodermis,6.60814347871989E-06)
(endodermis,0)
(endodermis,0)
(endodermis,0)
(endodermis,0)
(endodermis,0)
(endodermis,0)
(cortex,9.5355341294319E-06)
(cortex,2.1057864731946E-05)
(cortex,1.5669977484698E-05)
};
     \addplot 
 coordinates{
(xylem,8.8548394677423E-07)
(xylem,8.49207960018033E-07)
(xylem,1.82966958991188E-06)
(xylem,5.01832453727407E-07)
(xylem,6.31337603076415E-07)
(metaxylem,8.45054650059105E-07)
(metaxylem,0)
(parenchyma near,4.08132819251251E-05)
(parenchyma near,1.83620584272058E-05)
(parenchyma near,8.32828327462505E-06)
(parenchyma near,0)
(parenchyma near,0)
(parenchyma near,0)
(parenchyma far,3.11847940394294E-05)
(parenchyma far,3.19814426901767E-05)
(parenchyma far,2.94103241285456E-05)
(parenchyma far,2.07894487802615E-05)
(parenchyma far,0)
(endodermis,6.44738578951128E-06)
(endodermis,3.60117193456986E-06)
(endodermis,2.3746975565665E-06)
(endodermis,0)
(endodermis,0)
(endodermis,0)
(endodermis,0)
(endodermis,0)
(endodermis,0)
(cortex,3.62699100680599E-06)
(cortex,0)
(cortex,0)
};

\legend{742,743,744,745}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I recently wrote an [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186761/23160) to a related question: [Bars with same x index in stacked barplot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/186136/23160). Maybe you can take notes from the solution and apply it to your problem.